# MPI_Recv with list of sources

Tags: c, fortran, mpi

Is it possible to have a list of sources passed to an MPI_Recv (or equivalent) call?  Currently, my code looks something like:

```
do i=nod1,nod2
    call mpi_recv(tmp,n,MPI_REAL,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
    ... do stuff with tmp here
    call mpi_send(tmp,n,MPI_REAL,status(MPI_SOURCE),tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
enddo
```

Of course, this doesn't guarantee that it does what I want.  (if nod1 sends two messages here before nod2 can send one message, then nod2's message is not recieved during this iteration, which would be bad.)  In my application, that can't happen since nod1 and nod2 have other constraints which force them to be synchronized (enough) with each other ... but it got me wondering if there is way to specify a list of procs that are permitted to be recieved from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as such. However, you can use `MPI_Probe()` with `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`, and then compare the `MPI_SOURCE` field of the `status` object against your list of processes you want to receive from. If there's a match, you can then proceed to receive from that source with a regular blocking receive.

Comment: I've wondered about that ... is MPI_Probe guranteed to return info about a message only once?  What happens if it probes and recieves a "bad message"?  Then I have to probe again until I find a "good" message, but won't it keep returning the information about the "bad" message?

Comment: Basically, what Probe does is tell you what would have happened if you called Recv. It does not discard the message, however, and because messages in MPI are non-overtaking, repeated probes will probe the same message over and over again. If this is a problem, you can always loop through all ranks you wish to potentially receive from, and probe them individually.

Comment: Yeah, I realize I can do that, but there's a problem there since MPI_Probe is blocking -- If I specify a proc number in MPI_Probe, I once again am forcing an order of the messages I recieve.  I suppose the only solution is to post N MPI_Iprobes (one for each proc) and test whether those probes have come back -- It seems like this is a simple/common enough case that there would be an easier way to do it.